# Confused by Flask's behaviour

Tags: python, flask

I started by creating my Flask app the old school way: I had a Python package where I defined a variable called app, initialised it and then imported my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os

from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
app.secret_key = os.urandom(12)

from dashboard import forms, models, views
```

While adding unit tests to my project I found that I should use app factories so I created a factory:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os

def create_app()
  from flask import Flask

  app = Flask(__name__)
  app.config.from_object('config')
  app.secret_key = os.urandom(12)

app = create_app()
from dashboard import forms, models, views
```

Except that with the factory my views are not loaded. Any route I call returns a 404. Without the factory everything works fine.

How can I diagnose what's going on?

Comment: First, by providing an accurate picture of your code. Is the missing return value the problem? Hard to say, because the missing colon after `def create_app()` means it isn’t what’s really running… also, use Python 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `create_app` have to return `app` variable:

```
def create_app()
  from flask import Flask

  app = Flask(__name__)
  app.config.from_object('config')
  app.secret_key = os.urandom(12)

  return app
```

Because default return is `None`